# Is there a pathlib method for finding the complement of one path in another?

Tags: python, pathlib

Given two Python Pathlib paths in which one is a suffix of the other (of unknown depth),

```
x = Path("/a/b/c/d/e.ext")
y = Path("d/e.ext")
```

is there a "nice" way to find the complement of `y` in `x`? I.e. find:

```
z = Path("/a/b/c")
```

I'm thinking of perhaps a sort of inverse to the `relative_to()` method, but wasn't able to find something suitable in the docs or other SO questions.
Currently, I can do either of the following, but they are not very readable:

```
z = Path(*x.parts[:-len(y.parts)])
z = Path(str(x)[:-len(str(y))])
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such routine, but a simple string removal will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both paths to `str` and remove subpath to retrieve complement:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> x = Path("/a/b/c/d/e.ext")
>>> y = Path("d/e.ext")

>>> Path(str(x).replace(str(y), ""))
PosixPath('/a/b/c')
```

If subpath is not in path, it will leave path as it is.